# Trying to find iframe id (due to to dynamic iframes)

Tags: c#, linq, selenium

I'm not entirely sure what's wrong with this code. I get an `Object reference not set to an instance...` error.

code is as follows:

```
        var frameName = _driver.
        FindElement(By.Id(CrmCommon.contentpanel)).
        FindElements(By.TagName("iframe")).
        FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetCssValue("style").Contains("visible")).GetAttribute("id");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out, I should have been using GetAttribute in both places. I've put this into a private method which returns the ID.

Here:

```
    private string GetiFrameID()
    {
        return _pageManager.BrowserDriver
                                        .FindElement(By.Id(CrmCommon.contentpanel))
                                        .FindElements(By.TagName("iframe"))
                                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttribute("style")
                                        .Contains("visible"))
                                        .GetAttribute("id");
    }
```